# Youtube API Quota Exceeded Before Any Successful Request

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use Youtube API to download caption of a video. None of my requests were successful due to quotaExceeded error. However, I have not spent any quota other than request caption list to get the id of the caption.

```
request = youtube.captions().download(
    id="O-jAeIynN9yCRz1el0-7JaFewbFekv8NUbhAZBwVajw="
)
# TODO: For this request to work, you must replace "YOUR_FILE"
#       with the location where the downloaded content should be written.
fh = io.FileIO("/Users/joehuangx/Desktop/test", "wb")
```

Based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download), download caption requires 200 units in quota, which is within the range of daily limit.

[image: quota limit screenshot]

Comment: Go to the google cloud console under library find the YouTube data api -> manage - look for quota.  Please add a screen shot what your current quota is.

Comment: Thanks for the response, added my screenshot showing my quota status, but doesn't seem to show any usage.

Answer (score 1):

The default quota limit for this api when you first create a project is 10,000.  From time to time someone like yourself will start getting the quota exceeded error before ever making any requests. This always turns out to be that the their project quota is set to 0

As you can see from your quota picture your current quota is 0

[image]

I have posted this as an issue a number of times and there has never been a solution.  You have two options

1. Request for a quota extension.
2. delete the project your just created. Create a new one enable the Youtube data api again and see if it gives you the default quota then.

I have yet to have found any way of knowing what causes this to happen and YouTube isnt telling.

The only information i have is this issue [#211012781](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211012781)

> Hi. If you're seeing Queries per day quota set to 0 and the API is indeed enabled, then this means that your project’s access to YouTube Data API Service has been disabled.

> You should’ve received a notice via email regarding this action, which also contains the steps that need to be taken to regain the project’s access. But just in case you missed it, please fill out and submit the exceptions form below:

https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en

Comment: I noticed it happened once in a project i had that I stopped using.  I wonder if they randomly disable it in old projects.  But that's just a theory Please remember to accept the answer if it helps you will increase your rep.

Comment: I also believe that Google removes quotas for old accounts. I attempted to use a 10-year-old account, which had an allowance of "0 Queries per day" but "1,800,000 Queries per minute." The lack of daily quota made it unusable. I created a new project, which provided an allowance of "10,000 Queries per day."